# Adding an entry to a Multidimentonal Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I try to add an array element to an array if a certain condition is meet, before I push that array into an another array. Right now it adds the value as separate array and it is not in the same array.

```
<?php

for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    $ret1[] = array("A" . $i, "B" . $i);
    if ($i > 2) {
        $ret1[] = array("C" . $i);
    }
}    

print_r($ret1);

?>
```

**Current result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => A0
            [1] => B0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => A1
            [1] => B1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => A2
            [1] => B2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => A3
            [1] => B3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => C3
        )

)
```

**Expected result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => A0
            [1] => B0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => A1
            [1] => B1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => A2
            [1] => B2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => A3
            [1] => B3
            [2] => C3
        )

)
```

Comment: Just create an if/else statement and if the condition is met you add all 3 values inside an array, e.g. `$ret1[] = array(a, b, c)` and else you just add a and b as array.

Comment: What's not working about your example?

Comment: [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) should work, just remember that the first argument is expected to be a single dimension array so if you wanted to add to the 2nd level arrays then you would need `array_push($ret1[INDEX], VALUE)`

Comment: Thank you Rizier123 for editing/clarifying my question. It's easier to understand now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a temporary variable to define the array. Then you can decide to push another element to it based on your condition. Finally you can push the temporary array to your `$ret1` array to achieve the desired result.

```
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    $arr = ["A$i", "B$i"];
    if ($i > 2) {
        $arr[] = "C$i";
    }
    $ret1[] = $arr;
}
```

What you're doing is pushing 2 elements to the array in the last 2 iterations of your loop. One with a value of `["A3", "B3"]` and another with a value of `["C3"]` which just results in `[["A3", "B3"], ["C3"]]`, which isn't what you're after. By using the temporary variable `$arr` we defer pushing the final array to `$ret1` until after the conditional statement is executed or bypassed.

So for example, in the penultimate iteration of this loop the value of `$arr` is initially `["A3","B3"]`, then we push another value `"C3"` to the end of `$arr` based on `$i > 2` being `true`, which makes `$arr = ["A3","B3","C3"]`, and finally we push `$arr` to the end of the array `$ret1` giving us the final result `[ ..., 3 => ["A3","B3","C3"], ...]`

## Bonus notes

None of this is critical to your problem or your question, but I figured I'd throw it out there just in case.

In PHP, [double quoted strings](http://php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.syntax.double) give you automatic variable expansion. Which means that `"A$i" === "A" . $i`. So just something to consider. Additionally, there is a [short-hand syntax for arrays](http://php.net/language.types.array#example-99), which has been available [since PHP 5.4.0](http://php.net/migration54.new-features) and in my personal opinion is easier to write and read than using the traditional `array()` construct. So `array("A" . $i, "B" . $i) === ["A$i", "B$i"]`.

Comment: Very good explanation, and congratulations on finding a good opportunity to say penultimate.

Comment: Yea, I only usually get to say it once or twice a year so... feels great when I do :)

Comment: Thanks for the Bonus Notes. It really makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is not giving you the results you expect because each time you use

```
$ret1[] = something
```

PHP automatically creates a *new* index in `$ret`.

If you want to append another string to the array you have just inserted into `$ret` you can specify the current key with `$ret1[$i][] = "C" . $i;` instead of `$ret1[] = array("C" . $i);`.